# Delay jQuery fadeIn due to unwanted behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, fadein

How do I make my *.right-menu* DIV to fadein only after a couple of moments the mouse is hovering its parent *.right-menu-background* ? The thing is that when you move the cursor quickly in and out, *.right-menu* DIV is reappearing a lot of times after.

How do I delay animation for few ms?

Here's the code:

```
$(function(){
     $(".right-menu-background").hover(function(){
          $(this).find(".right-menu").fadeIn();
          }

,function(){
     $(this).find(".right-menu").fadeOut();
     }
);        
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a easy fix is to use [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$(function () {
    $(".right-menu-background").hover(function () {
        $(this).find(".right-menu").stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    }, function () {
        $(this).find(".right-menu").stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

using timer

```
$(function () {
    $(".right-menu-background").hover(function () {
        var el = $(this).find(".right-menu");
        var timer = setTimeout(function(){
            el.stop(true, true).fadeIn();
        }, 500);

        el.data('hovertimer', timer);
    }, function () {
        var el = $(this).find(".right-menu");
        clearTimeout(el.data('hovertimer'))
        el.stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function in front of fading calls `...stop(true, true)`

With those two parameters set to true, the animation queue is cleared and the last animation is played this will get ride of the weird effect

```
$(this).find(".right-menu").stop(true, true).fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.delay()` function.

Here is the code:

```
$(function(){
 $(".right-menu-background").hover(function(){
      $(this).find(".right-menu").delay(800).fadeIn(400);
      },function(){
 $(this).find(".right-menu").fadeOut(400);
 });        
});
```

Check the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mju7X/

Comment: This code does the same, it's just reapperaing in longer moments.